# Como resolver erro de referência no Visual Studio Community 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

Eu quero resolver um erro de referência quando clico em uma palavra. Utilizava o visual studio 2013 e tinha o **"resove > referência"**. Mas no **visual studio 2017 community** como posso resolver todas as dependências de referências?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No **Visual Studio 2017** a forma de resolver referências é através da opção `Quick Actions and Refactorings...`, que é o mesmo que aceder ao atalho `Ctrl + .`.

Pode também aceder à pequena lâmpada que aparece na barra vertical do lado esquerdo, onde lhe são mostradas as sugestões.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]